# How does squid understand the destination IP address in transparent mode

Tags: iptables, proxy, squid

In transparent mode, following iptable rules are used to redirect traffic to squid.

```
iptables -I PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128
```

As per my knowledge REDIRECT changes the destination IP address to the local interface's IP.

So when the traffic reaches squid, how does squid come to know where to forward it since the destination IP has changed now ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that with the `REDIRECT`, Squid cannot see the original intended destination IP; instead it will resolve the host provided by the client in the `Host:` HTTP header, which is mandatory in HTTP 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

That is very similar to the gateway.

When client host does not know where the destination host reside, it send the packet to the default gateway. And gateway define where that packet should be sent.

Transparent proxy do the same. All packets to the xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80 are diverted to the port 3128 instead of port mentioned in the packet header. Squid analyze the packet and its headers - `src`, `dst` and corresponding ports, and then submit the packet like gateway do, or immediately send an answer if it was cached before.

Main idea that destination port is stored within each packet while packet can be routed to the different hosts/ports in transit.